# Cordova app ANR on touch event only for Galaxy devices after updating to Android 8.0 or 8.1

Tags: android, cordova, galaxy, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

My Cordova app has been running fine on Galaxy devices for about two years.  For some reason, after our Galaxy users update to Android 8.0 or later the app will randomly freeze after receiving a touch event.  This only occurs when bringing the app from the background to the foreground.  I've created a debug report and can see that the app console isn't showing any errors.  Does anyone have ideas on how to fix this ANR or how I might debug it?

The error on the Play store's ANR & crashes section says the following:

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the
>   touched window has not finished processing certain input events that
>   were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 4. Wait
>   queue head age: 21951.5ms.)

This is the dumpsys activity lastanr from the bug report:

```
ACTIVITY MANAGER ACTIVITIES (dumpsys activity lastanr)
  ANR time: May 3, 2018 2:09:59 PM
  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 10.  Wait queue head age: 35192.4ms.

  ActivityStarter:
    mCurrentUser=0
    mLastStartReason=startActivityAsUser
    mLastStartActivityTimeMs=May 3, 2018 2:09:12 PM
    mLastStartActivityResult=2
    mLastStartActivityRecord:
     packageName=com.android.systemui processName=com.android.systemui
     launchedFromUid=10006 launchedFromPackage=com.android.systemui userId=0
     app=ProcessRecord{a0e12d3 2203:com.android.systemui/u0a6}
     Intent { flg=0x10804000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity }
     frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{6829b6fd0 #12289 A=com.android.systemui U=0 StackId=5 sz=1}
     taskAffinity=com.android.systemui
     realActivity=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity
     baseDir=/system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk
     dataDir=/data/user_de/0/com.android.systemui
     stateNotNeeded=true componentSpecified=true mActivityType=2
     compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f120991 icon=0x7f080362 theme=0x7f130102
     mLastReportedConfigurations:
      mGlobalConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc410mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) s.11 mkbd/h desktop/d ?dc}
      mOverrideConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc410mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) s.11 mkbd/h desktop/d ?dc}
     CurrentConfiguration={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc410mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) s.13 mkbd/h desktop/d ?dc}
     taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" primaryColor=ff212121
      backgroundColor=ff303030
      statusBarColor=0
      navigationBarColor=0
     launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-3h5m33s450ms
     haveState=false icicle=null
     state=PAUSED stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
     keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_NOT_SHOWN
     fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=3
     frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
     mActivityType=RECENTS_ACTIVITY_TYPE
     waitingVisible=true nowVisible=true lastVisibleTime=-46s329ms
     resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
     mLastReportedMultiWindowMode=false mLastReportedPictureInPictureMode=false
     maxAspectRatio=0.0
     maxAspectRatioInMeta=0.0
     requestTransientBarDelay=0
     vrActivityType=0
     useDeviceDefaultTheme=false
     multiScreenAttrs=MultiScreenAttrs, mBaseDisplayId=0, mBaseActivity=false}
    mLastHomeActivityStartResult=0
    mLastHomeActivityStartRecord:
     packageName=com.sec.android.app.launcher processName=com.sec.android.app.launcher
     launchedFromUid=0 launchedFromPackage=null userId=0
     app=ProcessRecord{f44f680 3633:com.sec.android.app.launcher/u0a86}
     Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10800100 cmp=com.sec.android.app.launcher/.activities.LauncherActivity bnds=[231,1101][430,1396] }
     frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{544fb3fd0 #12283 I=com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
     taskAffinity=null
     realActivity=com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher
     baseDir=/system/priv-app/TouchWizHome_2017/TouchWizHome_2017.apk
     dataDir=/data/user/0/com.sec.android.app.launcher
     stateNotNeeded=true componentSpecified=false mActivityType=1
     compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f090025 icon=0x7f0200d6 theme=0x7f0f0027
     mLastReportedConfigurations:
      mGlobalConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc410mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) s.9 mkbd/h desktop/d ?dc}
      mOverrideConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc410mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) s.9 mkbd/h desktop/d ?dc}
     CurrentConfiguration={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc410mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) s.13 mkbd/h desktop/d ?dc}
     taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" primaryColor=ff51b0d3
      backgroundColor=fffafafa
      statusBarColor=0
      navigationBarColor=0
     launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-3h41m49s87ms
     haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=22812]
     state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
     keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_NOT_SHOWN
     fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=2
     frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
     mActivityType=HOME_ACTIVITY_TYPE
     waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-13m39s663ms
     connections=[]
     resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
     mLastReportedMultiWindowMode=false mLastReportedPictureInPictureMode=false
     maxAspectRatio=0.0
     maxAspectRatioInMeta=2.1
     requestTransientBarDelay=0
     vrActivityType=0
     useDeviceDefaultTheme=true
     multiScreenAttrs=MultiScreenAttrs, mBaseDisplayId=0, mBaseActivity=false}
    mStartActivity:
     packageName=com.android.systemui processName=com.android.systemui
     launchedFromUid=10006 launchedFromPackage=com.android.systemui userId=0
     app=null
     Intent { flg=0x10c04000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity }
     frontOfTask=false task=TaskRecord{6829b6fd0 #12289 A=com.android.systemui U=0 StackId=5 sz=1}
     taskAffinity=com.android.systemui
     realActivity=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity
     baseDir=/system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk
     dataDir=/data/user_de/0/com.android.systemui
     stateNotNeeded=true componentSpecified=true mActivityType=2
     compat=null labelRes=0x7f120991 icon=0x7f080362 theme=0x7f130102
     mLastReportedConfigurations:
      mGlobalConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc410mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) s.13 mkbd/h desktop/d ?dc}
      mOverrideConfig={0 0.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = -1 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?ldr ?wideColorGamut ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/? mkbd/? desktop/? ?dc}
     CurrentConfiguration={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc410mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) s.13 mkbd/h desktop/d ?dc}
     pendingOptions=ActivityOptions(228770256), mPackageName=com.android.systemui, mAnimationType=9, mStartX=0, mStartY=0, mWidth=0, mHeight=0
     launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=0
     haveState=true icicle=null
     state=INITIALIZING stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
     keysPaused=false inHistory=false visible=false sleeping=false idle=false mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_NOT_SHOWN
     fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=3
     frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
     mActivityType=RECENTS_ACTIVITY_TYPE
     resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
     mLastReportedMultiWindowMode=false mLastReportedPictureInPictureMode=false
     maxAspectRatio=0.0
     maxAspectRatioInMeta=0.0
     requestTransientBarDelay=0
     vrActivityType=0
     useDeviceDefaultTheme=false
     multiScreenAttrs=MultiScreenAttrs, mBaseDisplayId=0, mBaseActivity=false}
    mIntent=Intent { flg=0x10c04000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity }
    mLaunchSingleTop=false mLaunchSingleInstance=true mLaunchSingleTask=false mLaunchFlags=0x10804000 mDoResume=true mAddingToTask=false
```

This is a chunk from the logs that center around the touch event that it is waiting on.  The touch event that it hangs on happens at `5-03 14:09:23.836`:

```
05-03 14:09:19.687  1041   964 28776 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: setStreamVolumeIndex() stream 8, device 00000002, index 3
05-03 14:09:19.694  1000  1518  2360 I EDMNativeHelperService: isAVRCPProfileEnabled
05-03 14:09:19.697  1000  1518  2360 D BluetoothSecureManagerService: isSecureModeEnabled
05-03 14:09:19.697  1000  1518  2360 D BluetoothSecureManagerService: getSecureModeSetting, name: secure_mode_enable
05-03 14:09:19.701  1002  2165  2895 V Avrcp   : sendPlaybackStatus : 2
05-03 14:09:20.188  1002  2165  2889 D A2dpStateMachine: isDualPlayEnabled : false
05-03 14:09:20.192  1002  2165  2889 D A2dpStateMachine: isDualPlayEnabled : false
05-03 14:09:20.513  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:20.576  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:20.578  1000   992  3854 I LocSvc_libulp: ulp_brain_process_gnss_sv_report, gnss sv report cnt = 1180, gnss pos report cnt = 12,strong sv cnt = 0
05-03 14:09:20.579  1000  1518  8953 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: SV Count : 2      (PRN, Constellation, SNR, Used)
05-03 14:09:20.580  1000  1518  8953 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: (6, GPS, 18.3, 0) (22, GLONASS, 16.6, 0) 
05-03 14:09:20.672  1000  1518  2548 D ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10251 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: nxtgenphone, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
05-03 14:09:20.918  1000  1518  1518 D TelephonyManager: getCellLocation : Caller (PID / UID / TID): 1518 / 1000 / 1518
05-03 14:09:20.922 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 21 -104 -17 -34 2147483647 0 2147483647 0x4000 P gsm|lte level=4
05-03 14:09:20.923 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): getMobileIconGroup(): 13
05-03 14:09:20.923 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): updateATTMobileIconGroup(): 13
05-03 14:09:20.939 10093  3507 15037 I EventLogSendingHelper: Sending log events.
05-03 14:09:21.514  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:21.576  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:21.577  1000   992  3854 I LocSvc_libulp: ulp_brain_process_gnss_sv_report, gnss sv report cnt = 1181, gnss pos report cnt = 12,strong sv cnt = 0
05-03 14:09:21.578  1000  1518  8953 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: SV Count : 2      (PRN, Constellation, SNR, Used)
05-03 14:09:21.578  1000  1518  8953 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: (6, GPS, 18.3, 0) (22, GLONASS, 16.7, 0) 
05-03 14:09:21.619  1041   964 28577 W libutils.threads: Thread (this=0xe98b4730): don't call waitForExit() from this Thread object's thread. It's a guaranteed deadlock!
05-03 14:09:21.754  1000  1518  1900 D ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10069 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: nxtgenphone, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
05-03 14:09:21.818  1000  1518  1900 D SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm calling from uid:10069 pid :11770 / op:PendingIntent{f871447: PendingIntentRecord{a9b7474 com.samsung.android.email.provider startService}}
05-03 14:09:22.154  1000  1518  1518 D TelephonyManager: getCellLocation : Caller (PID / UID / TID): 1518 / 1000 / 1518
05-03 14:09:22.157 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 22 -104 -17 -32 2147483647 0 2147483647 0x4000 P gsm|lte level=4
05-03 14:09:22.157 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): getMobileIconGroup(): 13
05-03 14:09:22.158 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): updateATTMobileIconGroup(): 13
05-03 14:09:22.329  1000  1518  2291 E Watchdog: !@Sync 442 [2018-05-03 14:09:22.328]
05-03 14:09:22.515  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:22.577  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:22.578  1000   992  3854 I LocSvc_libulp: ulp_brain_process_gnss_sv_report, gnss sv report cnt = 1182, gnss pos report cnt = 12,strong sv cnt = 0
05-03 14:09:22.580  1000  1518  2141 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: SV Count : 2      (PRN, Constellation, SNR, Used)
05-03 14:09:22.580  1000  1518  2141 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: (6, GPS, 15.9, 0) (22, GLONASS, 17.3, 0) 
05-03 14:09:22.779  1000  1518  7168 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.bridgehaul.app
05-03 14:09:22.780  1000  1518  7168 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.bridgehaul.app
05-03 14:09:23.206  1000  1518  2360 D ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10251 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: nxtgenphone, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
05-03 14:09:23.371  1000   634   888 I SensorsGrip: GripSensor: grip data = 2
05-03 14:09:23.375  1000  1518  1518 D MotionRecognitionService: cable disconnected
05-03 14:09:23.375  1000  1518  1518 D MotionRecognitionService:  == >> GripVal = 0
05-03 14:09:23.375  1000  1518  1518 I MotionRecognitionService: GripWifi disabled 
05-03 14:09:23.375  1000  1518  1518 D MotionRecognitionService: clear SAR_DEVICE_GRIP
05-03 14:09:23.376  1000  1518  1822 E MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
05-03 14:09:23.397  1000  1518  1822 D MotionRecognitionService: clear TransmitPower  value : 1
05-03 14:09:23.397  1000  1518  1822 D MotionRecognitionService: clear TransmitPower  value : 1
05-03 14:09:23.514  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:23.575  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:23.576  1000   992  3854 I LocSvc_libulp: ulp_brain_process_gnss_sv_report, gnss sv report cnt = 1183, gnss pos report cnt = 12,strong sv cnt = 0
05-03 14:09:23.577  1000  1518  2142 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: SV Count : 2      (PRN, Constellation, SNR, Used)
05-03 14:09:23.577  1000  1518  2142 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: (6, GPS, 15.9, 0) (22, GLONASS, 17.3, 0) 
05-03 14:09:23.836  1000  1518  1881 D InputReader: Input event(10): value=1 when=13299900020000
05-03 14:09:23.836  1000  1518  1881 D InputReader: Input event(10): value=1 when=13299900020000
05-03 14:09:23.836  1000  1518  1881 I InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.1074 ] when=13299900020000
05-03 14:09:23.837  1000  1518  1880 I InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (2203): action: 0x4, toolType: 1
05-03 14:09:23.837  1000  1518  1880 I InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (2203): action: 0x4, toolType: 1
05-03 14:09:23.837  1000  1518  1880 I InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (29407): action: 0x0, toolType: 1
05-03 14:09:23.902  1000  1518  1518 D TelephonyManager: getCellLocation : Caller (PID / UID / TID): 1518 / 1000 / 1518
05-03 14:09:23.904 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 21 -104 -16 -28 2147483647 0 2147483647 0x4000 P gsm|lte level=4
05-03 14:09:23.904 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): getMobileIconGroup(): 13
05-03 14:09:23.904 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): updateATTMobileIconGroup(): 13
05-03 14:09:23.910  1000  1518  1881 D InputReader: Input event(10): value=0 when=13299974522000
05-03 14:09:23.910  1000  1518  1881 D InputReader: Input event(10): value=0 when=13299974522000
05-03 14:09:23.910  1000  1518  1881 I InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=13299974522000
05-03 14:09:23.911  1000  1518  1880 I InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (29407): action: 0x1, toolType: 1
05-03 14:09:23.990  1000  1518  1543 I ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{68de48d u0 com.duapps.recorder/com.duapps.screen.recorder.DaemonService}
05-03 14:09:24.109  1000  3014  3014 D io_stats: !@   8,0 r 1110284 44014520 w 235798 3154636 d 18435 624760 f 80322 85410 iot 767270 577539 th 194788 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 13300.172
05-03 14:09:24.158  1000  1518  1543 I ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{6074b90 u0 com.duapps.recorder/com.duapps.screen.recorder.DuJobService}
05-03 14:09:24.197  1000  1518  1900 D BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
05-03 14:09:24.198  1000  1518  1900 D BatteryService: level:69, scale:100, status:3, health:2, present:true, voltage: 3915, temperature: 275, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:false, POGO powered:false, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303827, invalid charger:0, maxChargingCurrent:0, maxChargingVoltage:0, chargeCounter:2003728
05-03 14:09:24.198  1000  1518  1900 D BatteryService: online:1, current avg:-819, charge type:0, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:280000, batterySWSelfDischarging:false, misc_event:0, current_event:64, current_now:-278
05-03 14:09:24.198  1000  1518  1518 D BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
05-03 14:09:24.202  1000  1518  1518 I MotionRecognitionService: On Battery, 0
05-03 14:09:24.202  1000  1518  1518 I MotionRecognitionService: disconnected - grip enable
05-03 14:09:24.202  1000  1518  1518 D SensorManager: registerListener fail :: 27, SX9320 Grip Sensor, 200000, 0,  
05-03 14:09:24.202  1000  1518  1518 D MotionRecognitionService:   mCableConnection= 0
05-03 14:09:24.202  1000  1518  1518 D SamsungPhoneWindowManager: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED - Level :: 69, battStatus :: 3
05-03 14:09:24.205 u0_a6  2203  2203 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
05-03 14:09:24.206  1000  1518  1550 D UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_CHARGING_STATE = 0
05-03 14:09:24.208  1002  2165  2165 V HeadsetService: Received Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
05-03 14:09:24.210  1002  2165  2886 D HeadsetStateMachine: Connected process message: 10, size: 1
05-03 14:09:24.210 u0_a6  2203  2203 D BatteryController: onReceive-ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : mLevel=69, mBatteryStatus=3
05-03 14:09:24.210  1000  2506  2677 D EPDG -- SIM0 [EpdgSubScription]: android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED intent received.
05-03 14:09:24.211 u0_a6  2203  2203 D PowerUI : priorPlugType = 0 mPlugType =  0
05-03 14:09:24.215 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): onDataActivity: direction=3
05-03 14:09:24.215 10100 23485 23485 D BatteryManager: ***Receiving Battery Change 69.0% ***
05-03 14:09:24.216  1000  2506  2677 D EPDG -- SIM0 [EpdgSubScription]: onDataActivity: direction=3
05-03 14:09:24.216 10100 23485 23485 D BatteryManager: ***Receiving Battery Change1 0.69% ***
05-03 14:09:24.216 10100 23485 23485 D BatteryManager: ***Receiving Battery Change2 0.15% ***
05-03 14:09:24.216 10100 23485 23485 D BatteryManager: ***Receiving Battery Change3 false% ***
05-03 14:09:24.244 u0_a6  2203  2203 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleStatusBarState( false )
05-03 14:09:24.382  1000  1518  1518 D TelephonyManager: getCellLocation : Caller (PID / UID / TID): 1518 / 1000 / 1518
05-03 14:09:24.384 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 21 -105 -16 -24 2147483647 0 2147483647 0x4000 P gsm|lte level=4
05-03 14:09:24.384 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): getMobileIconGroup(): 13
05-03 14:09:24.384 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): updateATTMobileIconGroup(): 13
05-03 14:09:24.515  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:24.576  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:24.576  1000   992  3854 I LocSvc_libulp: ulp_brain_process_gnss_sv_report, gnss sv report cnt = 1184, gnss pos report cnt = 12,strong sv cnt = 0
05-03 14:09:24.577  1000  1518  2141 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: SV Count : 2      (PRN, Constellation, SNR, Used)
05-03 14:09:24.577  1000  1518  2141 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: (6, GPS, 15.9, 0) (22, GLONASS, 17.3, 0) 
05-03 14:09:24.657  1000  1518  2548 D ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10251 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: nxtgenphone, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
05-03 14:09:24.819  5004 19572 19647 I ReschedulableTimer: [#CMH#] ReschedulableTimer started 
05-03 14:09:25.110  1000  1518  7168 D SSRM:t  : SIOP:: AP = 330, PST = 289 (W:15), BAT = 275, USB = 274, CHG = 309, CP = 301
05-03 14:09:25.222  1000  2506  2677 D EPDG -- SIM0 [EpdgSubScription]: onDataActivity: direction=1
05-03 14:09:25.222 u0_a6  2203  2610 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/1): onDataActivity: direction=1
05-03 14:09:25.514  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:25.574  1000   992  1143 I LocSvc_ApiV02: <--- globalEventCb line 162 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
05-03 14:09:25.575  1000   992  3854 I LocSvc_libulp: ulp_brain_process_gnss_sv_report, gnss sv report cnt = 1185, gnss pos report cnt = 12,strong sv cnt = 0
05-03 14:09:25.577  1000  1518  2141 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: SV Count : 2      (PRN, Constellation, SNR, Used)
05-03 14:09:25.578  1000  1518  2141 D GnssLocationProvider_ex: (6, GPS, 16.1, 0) (22, GLONASS, 18.3, 0) 
05-03 14:09:25.730  1000  1518  3556 D ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10251 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: nxtgenphone, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
05-03 14:09:26.039  1000  1518  1785 D SamsungAlarmManager: Expired : 8
05-03 14:09:26.040  1000  1518  1785 V SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 10026 action=com.google.android.gms.auth.authzen.cryptauth.DEVICE_STATE_CHECK_DELAY_COMPLETE alarm=Alarm{7641d9d type 3 when 23627321 com.google.android.gms}
05-03 14:09:26.045  1000  1518  1785 I ActivityManager: KPU : put [com.samsung.android.scloud] : 18756 K
05-03 14:09:26.055  1000  1518  1785 I ActivityManager: Killing 24177:com.samsung.android.scloud/5009 (adj 906): DHA:empty #25
05-03 14:09:26.058  1000  1518  1785 I ActivityManager: KPU : put [com.samsung.cmh:CMH] : 17535 K
05-03 14:09:26.058  1000  1518  1785 I ActivityManager: Killing 19572:com.samsung.cmh:CMH/5004 (adj 906): DHA:empty #25
05-03 14:09:26.094  1000  1518  3556 D ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10026 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: nxtgenphone, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
05-03 14:09:26.095 10026  3403 28657 I Authzen : [DeviceStateSyncManager] The server is in sync with current state. Nothing to do
05-03 14:09:26.123  5004 28194 28194 I DCMServiceController: [#CMH#] shutdown () called 
05-03 14:09:26.124  5004 28087 28087 I EnhanceService: [EnhanceService] onDestroy () called 
05-03 14:09:26.132  5004 26792 26792 I LPService: [#MLP#] On destroy 
05-03 14:09:26.133  5004 26792 26792 I LPServiceController: [#MLP#] Shutting down learning service... 
05-03 14:09:26.140  5013  2371  4494 D ProcessObserver_FLP: onProcessDied, 19572/5004
05-03 14:09:26.140   nfc  2472  2514 D ForegroundUtils: could not check pending caller
05-03 14:09:26.142 10267  3141  3218 V IQBridge: [IQPorting_MasterBridgeWrite] --> Agent request to write [16] bytes from [0x708e4b2508]
05-03 14:09:26.142 10267  3141  3218 V IQBridge: [IQPorting_MasterBridgeWrite] [16] <-- IQ_PORTING_OK
05-03 14:09:26.143  5013  2371  4494 D ProcessObserver_FLP: onProcessDied, 24177/5009
05-03 14:09:26.143   nfc  2472  2514 D ForegroundUtils: could not check pending caller
05-03 14:09:26.144 10267  3141  3218 V IQBridge: [IQPorting_MasterBridgeWrite] --> Agent request to write [16] bytes from [0x708e4b2508]
05-03 14:09:26.144 10267  3141  3218 V IQBridge: [IQPorting_MasterBridgeWrite] [16] <-- IQ_PORTING_OK
05-03 14:09:26.227  1000  2506  2677 D EPDG -- SIM0 [EpdgSubScription]: onDataActivity: direction=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally were able to track down and fix the issue so I'm posting the solution for us in case it helps someone else.  We have theories on why this is happening, but we can't say for sure the exact cause so I'll summarize the section of code that was causing the problem.

The culprit of the freezing was an interval that we set up to run once every minute.  The interval called `$http` (AngularJS) a few times which is a promise.  In order to fix the issue, we slowed down the interval to once every 15 minutes instead of every minute.  That solved the issue and our ANRs have vanished.